# метки joomla переопределить шаблон

Tags: joomla, joomla3

В joomla есть вывод всех меток через пункт меню = index.php?option=com_tags&view=tags

необходимо чтобы выводил не только метки, но и вытягивал материалы этих меток. Кто знает как сформировать запрос?

По меткам мы легко можем вытащить id - а по id с помощью цикла достучаться до самих материалов. Интересует синтаксис мероприятия, не получается(